# NLog is not logging

Tags: asp.net, nlog

I am using the new NLog 2.0.
I have set it up both manually and with the  aid of NuGet on 2 different platforms:

1) on a Visual Web Developer express 2010 back at home.

2) On a Visual Studio 2010 in office.

In both cases I just cant get it to log.

I have read all of the options suggested [here](http://nlog-project.org/wiki/Logging_is_not_working_-_how_to_troubleshoot_it?) with no luck.

I am using the very basic configuration from the first tutorial.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<nlog xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  throwExceptions="true">

<targets>
 <target name="logfile" xsi:type="File" fileName="${basedir}/file.txt" />
</targets>

 <rules>
  <logger name="*" minlevel="Info" writeTo="logfile"/>
 </rules>
</nlog>
```

And here is how I am calling the logger:

```
public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    Logger logger = LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();

    protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnInit(e);

        logger.Fatal("Hello Log!");
    }
}
```

I get no exceptions!

Am I doing anything wrong here??
What am I missing.

PS

I have set the NLog.config to "Copy always" so that's not the case either.

Comment: I've tested it locally and it works for me with your config file and code. Could you provide us with a sample project in which this situation occurs ?

Comment: I had to restart Visual Studio and computer in office and it suddenly start working.

It didn't occur to me that this is needed!

Any way sorry for that...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to restart Visual Studio and it suddenly start working.

It didn't occur to me that this is needed!

Any way sorry for that...